# Eloquent 'hasOne' selects both Id and the object behind the id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Project I've 2 tables:

MyAwesomeTable

```
ID | NAME | SOMEMOREINFO | ...
```

MySecondTable

```
ID | MyAwesomeTable_ID | SOMEOTHERDATA
```

Sorry for the weird formatting, but I do not know how to format tables in Stackoverflow correctly.

In my PHP I've got the following Model.

```
public class MySecondTable {
    ...

    public function awesomeTable() {
         return $this->hasOne('App\Models\MyAwesomeTable', 'id', 'MyAwesomeTable_ID');
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to get the entries of my `MySecondTable` with the following code, the JSON which is generated contains the `MyAwesomeTable_ID` AND the resolved `awesomeTable`.
How can I achieve to only get the resolved `awesomeTable`, without needing to call something like `removeColumns`.

```
$entries = MySecondTable::with(['awesomeTable'])->get();
```

What the call gives me is:

```
{
    ...
    'MyAwesomeTable_ID' : 1, // I Don't want this entry
    'awesomeTable' : {
        'id': 1,
        'name' : 'some name',
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want something to appear in the default select-list of a model, add that property to the `$hidden` array of that model,

```php
public class MySecondTable {
    // An array of properties that should not appear 
    // in the default select-list or JSON output
    protected $hidden = ['MyAwesomeTable_ID']; 

    public function awesomeTable() {
        // You can just define relation like this, the if you follow Laravel naming-conventions
        return $this->hasOne(MyAwesomeTable::class); 
        // return $this->hasOne('App\Models\MyAwesomeTable', 'id', 'MyAwesomeTable_ID');
    }
}
```

- [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)